# How to draw something around a pnode in pstricks?

Tags: pstricks

I would like to invoke `myfun` around a node `mynode` in pstricks, but do not know how to process. An example below:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\myfun(#1,#2)
{
    \psline[linewidth=0.75\pslinewidth]{<->}(! #1 0.25 sub #2 0.1 add)(! #1 0.25 add #2 0.1 add)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)

% my implementation
\myfun(1,1)

% what I want: (i) define a node; (ii) draw \myfun around it
\pnode(1,1){mynode}
% but how to define `\myfun(mynode)`?
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mmm… Not very clear. How can you draw `\myfun`  *around* something, since it's not a closed curve. Could you explain more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bernard My bad. To articulate, I would like to call `\myfun` whose input is a 2D coordinate. I am asking what is the (canonical) way to define such a function whose only input is a node.

Comment: If it is non-empt-y, you can use `\rnode`, or `\Rnode{node name}{\myfun}` if I understand well what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example updates the way `\myfun` works. Instead of explicitly taking an `(x,y)` argument, it takes a more generic `(<coordinate>)` argument, which could be a node, `x,y` coordinates, `r;t` coordinates or whatever. Fundamentally the update sets a new node `MyNoDe` for the coordinate argument passed and use `\psGetNodeCenter` to extract `MyNoDe.x` (the `x` coordinate) and `MyNoDe.y` (the `y`-coordinate).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\myfun(#1){
  \pnode(#1){MyNoDe}% Set temporary node
  \psline
    [linewidth = 0.75\pslinewidth]% options
    {<->}% style
    (! \psGetNodeCenter{MyNoDe} MyNoDe.x MyNoDe.y)% from
    (! \psGetNodeCenter{MyNoDe} MyNoDe.x 0.25 add MyNoDe.y 0.1 add)% to
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
  % my implementation
  \myfun(1,1)

  % what I want: (i) define a node; (ii) draw \myfun around it
  \pnode(0.5,1){mynode}
  \myfun(mynode)

  \myfun(1.5;30)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I've updated the `\psline` inside `\myfun` to have a different `from` and `to` node; your example would draw a zero-length `\psline`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\myfun(#1){%
    \pcline[linewidth=0.75\pslinewidth,nodesep=2.5mm,offset=0.25]{<->}(#1)(#1)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)    
    \pnode(1,1){mynode}
    \myfun(mynode)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or as an alternative:

```
\def\myfun(#1){%
    \rput(#1){%
        \psline[linewidth=0.75\pslinewidth]{<->}(-0.25,0.1)(0.25,0.1)}}
```